# `shared_ptr` with deep copy for `omp parallel firstprivate`

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, smart-pointers

I have an object that is

1. polymorphic, so needs to be passed by pointer (*or variant but that seems like overkill*)
2. large enough and passed around frequently enough that it needs to be passed efficiently (i.e. not copied unnecessarily)
3. not thread safe, so needs to be copied for each thread when we enter an `omp parallel` section

Is there a way I can automatically declare appropriate copy semantics for this object?  My idea is

1. make my own wrapper class that contains a pointer to the object but does deep copies (*is there a smart pointer class that behaves like this already?*)
2. always pass the wrapper by reference so it **doesn't** get copied in function calls (*how do I check I haven't accidentally passed by value somewhere?*)
3. declare it as `firstprivate` for the `omp parallel` section so it **does** get copied for each thread

Is that sensible?  Is there a better way?

Edit: how about a copy constructor that checks whether `omp_get_thread_num()` has changed and performs pointer or deep copy as appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to manage the object, and implement a function:

```
shared_ptr<T> deepCopy(const shared_ptr<T>& obj);
```

that performs deep copy on request and returns another shared pointer. This function can then be used inside a parallel region to instantiate a private copy of `obj` where needed.

Comment: Have an upvote for reminding me I was making this too complicated :)  I chose a different option in the end.  `scoped_ptr` to handle the noncopying polymorphic semantics.  And inside that a wrapper to add thread safety to the object (will post up in another question).  Thus keeping the threading details and copying out of the top level algorithm.

Comment: Another update, revisiting the code a year later.  The trouble with `deepCopy` as suggested above is (I think) it will be called once for every iteration of the parallel for, when it was only needed once per thread.  So, the thing is to wrap the class in another that has deep copy semantics to pass it into the parallel region, then unwrap it inside the region for shallow copying.